# Suppressing Parts of the Legend in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I'm looking to remove or suppress levels of a ggplot2 legend without having to modify the data itself. Is this possible?

Here is some sample data:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = disp, group = gear)) +
    geom_point(aes(color = factor(cyl))) +
    scale_colour_manual(values = c("#85D4E3", "#CEAB07", "#29211F")) +
    theme_bw()
```

To try and remove select levels, such as "8", from the legend I've tried things like the code modification below. This simply changes "8" to NA, and does not remove that level of the legend.

```
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = disp, group = gear)) +
    geom_point(aes(color = factor(cyl))) +
    scale_colour_manual(values = c("#85D4E3", "#CEAB07", "#29211F"), labels = c("4", "6", NULL)) +
    theme_bw()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close, instead of changing labels change the breaks

```
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = disp, group = gear)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = factor(cyl))) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("#85D4E3", "#CEAB07", "#29211F"), breaks  = c("4", "6")) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: I just tried this out on my end. It causes the legend to not show up at all. Did this not happen on your end?

Comment: Yeah that code works for me, I'll edit my answer and add the plot. Are you trying this on your own data?

Comment: Yes, that's strange. When I try it on my data (set-up really similar to the example provided) it doesn't show the legend altogether.   ggplot(data = sampAmp, aes(x = Cycle, y = ΔRn, group = sampleName)) +
    geom_point(aes(color = factor(sampleName))) +
    scale_colour_manual(values = col, breaks  = c("1:10", "1:100", "1:1E3", "1:1E4", "1:1E5", "1:1E6", "1:1E7", "1:1E8", "St"))

Comment: I just realized my error. The names in the dataset differed from the names I called in the breaks. When I corrected this, the code works as expected. Sorry about that, and thank you for your assistance!